# How do I make async_read_some of asio to call a callback?

Tags: c++, serial-port, asio

I'm trying to use serial_port of asio(standlone) to get data from a device. But I can't read even a byte.
I post a screenshoot of the example usage found from documentation website as below :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9wVU.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJXYw.png)
https://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.24.0/doc/asio/reference/basic_serial_port/async_read_some.html
There are 3 question I have:

1. What is the specific type of the first parameter of async_read_some? std::vector<uint8_t>, for example?
2. How to bind a class member function as the callback/handler?
3. Is it right that we just make sure io_context.run() run on a background thread and call async_read_some just once?

I'll appreciate it if you guys could help me check out my code or give some advice.

```
class NmeaSource {
public:
    explicit NmeaSource(std::shared_ptr<asio::io_context> io, const nlohmann::json& settings);
    void parse();
    void handle(const asio::error_code& error, // Result of operation.
        std::size_t bytes_transferred           // Number of bytes read.
    );

private:
    void open();

    std::string m_port;
    int m_baudrate;
    std::shared_ptr<asio::io_context> m_io;
    std::shared_ptr<asio::serial_port> m_serial;
    unsigned char m_readBuffer[1024];
};

NmeaSource::NmeaSource(std::shared_ptr<asio::io_context> io, const nlohmann::json& settings)
    :m_io(io)
{
    try {
        setPort(settings.at("port"));
        setBaudrate(settings.at("baudrate"));
        //LOG("");
        std::cout << "port: " << m_port << ", baudrate: " << m_baudrate << std::endl;
    }
    catch (nlohmann::json::basic_json::type_error& e1) {
        std::cout << "type is wrong " << e1.what() << std::endl;
        throw e1;
    }
    catch (nlohmann::json::basic_json::out_of_range& e2) {
        std::cout << "key is not found " << e2.what() << std::endl;
        throw e2;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cout << "unknown error"<< std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }

    open();

}

void NmeaSource::open()
{
    m_serial = std::make_shared<asio::serial_port>(*m_io);

    asio::error_code ec;
    m_serial->open(m_port, ec);
    if (!ec) {
        asio::serial_port_base::baud_rate baudrate(m_baudrate);
        m_serial->set_option(baudrate);
        std::cout << "successfully" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "failed " << ec.message() <<std::endl;
    }
}

void NmeaSource::handle(const asio::error_code& error, // Result of operation.
    std::size_t bytes_transferred           // Number of bytes read.
)
{
    if (!error) {
        std::cout << bytes_transferred << " bytes read!" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << error.message() << std::endl;
    }
}

void NmeaSource::parse()
{
    m_serial->async_read_some(
        asio::buffer(m_readBuffer, 1024),
        std::bind(&NmeaSource::handle, this,
            std::placeholders::_1,
            std::placeholders::_2)
    );

}

int main()
{
    auto io = std::make_shared<asio::io_context>();
    //std::thread t(std::bind(static_cast<size_t(asio::io_service::*)()>(&asio::io_service::run), io.get()));
    std::thread t([&io]() {io->run(); });
    NmeaSource rtk(io, nlohmann::json{ {"port", "COM3"}, {"baudrate", 115200} });
    rtk.parse();
    for (;;)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5));
    }
}
```

[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpsgy.png)

Comment: In your main you create an` io_context` and then directly call `io_context::run()`. An `io_context` "consumes" any handlers assigned to it and then returns. So in your example nothing is going to actually happen.

Comment: Try `io->run()` after the `rtk` declaration or after `rtk.parse()` and see what happens

Comment: @guard3 Thank you! It works for me! I also find that I need to create an asio::io_context::work object to prevent io event loop from quitting.